# How is the total gate charge of a MOSFET affected by the temperature?

Tags: mosfet, nmos, charge, pmos, temperature-coefficient

For P- and N-MOSFETs, Vgsth will decrease (in absolute value) when the temperature rises.

- What is the impact of the temperature on the total gate charge for P- and N-MOSFETs?
- What is the order of magnitude of the variation?

Comment: Have you any evidence that the gate capacitance changes with temperature? Are you considering switching applications or, are you considering analogue applications? Best if you provide an image of the circuit you are considering.

Comment: No, I have no evidence that the gate charge is impacted, that is my question.
The circuit is an H-bridge, with an asymmetric gate driver impedance
the impedance on the gate it tuned to reduce EMC disturbance, this impacts the turn-on/off time, and I would like to know it this time will be sensitive to component spread and temperature

I edit the answer for the schematics

Comment: the transistor in use is IRFR9310TRLPBF-BE3, I don't see spread or temperature dependencies of the gate charge in the datasheet

Comment: Data sheet link: https://www.vishay.com/docs/91284/sihfr931.pdf <-- I left this link for the convenience of anyone making an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/14692-mosfet-tutorial) application note:

> Gate charge values vary slightly with drain current and drain-source
> voltage but not with temperature.

Their definition of 'slightly' is of the order of 10%, so we might presume any variation with temperature (there surely is *some*) is of the order of 1%.

Comment: Indeed, page 11, there is this: "because MOSFET switching energy is not
sensitive to temperature" where switching energy is a consequence of the turn-on/off time and therefore of the gate charge. this supports that the temperature impact is minor.